# How to generate menu items before menu opened

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a menu in a WPF application that I would like to update each time the user open it because the MenuItems are from a DataBase that can change at any time.

Is there a way to rebuild theses MenuItems each time by subscribing to an event or something?

Regards

Comment: I would highly suggest not storing menu items in the data base.. I am working currently with some CRAP that someone has written like this prior to me coming on board at this company..it's the worst thing to do ever in my opinion.. just create the menu items and use a master page that's just my opinion can you say `REFACTOR`

Comment: This is not the UI logic that is stored in the database but just the data you may want open and edit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider binding the menu items to some sort of collection in your view model. The collection would contain the menu items, and the UI would bind to it, through a data template.

The blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/10/23/binding-menus-using-heirarchicaldatatemplates.aspx should help describe this technique. Another post at http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/using-hierarchical-data-template-with-menu-item/ also contains good information.